# JPA 2 Criteria API case insensitive condition without metamodel usage

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

How to create Case-insensitive Criteria Query without metamodel usage?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
   CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Resident> criteria = builder.createQuery(Resident.class);
    Root<Resident> personRoot = criteria.from(Resident.class);

    criteria.where(builder.and(
            builder.equal(builder.upper(personRoot.get("firstName")), filter.getFirstName())),  //ERROR
            builder.equal(personRoot.get("lastName"), filter.getLastName()));
```

But it produce error:

> method upper in interface javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
>   [ERROR] required: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression
>   [ERROR] found: javax.persistence.criteria.Path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
Expression<String>  firstName = personRoot.get("firstName");

criteria.where(builder.and(
            builder.equal(builder.upper(firstName ), filter.getFirstName())),   
            builder.equal(personRoot.get("lastName"), filter.getLastName()));
```

seems like it method upper has some problems with accepting path

Answer (score 5):

This should compile:

```
...builder.upper(personRoot.<String>get("firstName"))...
```